# JsonSerializer - serializing arbitrary values, and deserializing based on a memory segment that is followed by more data

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a custom serialization interface:

```
interface ISerializer<T>
{
  void Serialize(T value, IBufferWriter<byte> writer);
  T Deserialize(ref SequenceReader<byte> source);
}
```

The sequence passed to Deserialize contains the data previously written by Serialize(), but may contain more data thereafter, which the (de)serializer implementation must ignore/not consume.

Example: If a Serialize() call writes a byte sequence of [0x01, 0x02], then a the following call to Deserialize() may be invoked with a sequence reader containing [0x01, 0x02, ... more bytes ...].
The implementation must ensure to only read the first two bytes then, and not consume the rest.

Now, I'm trying to adapt System.Text.JSON serialization to this interface. At first, my implementation looked like this:

```
class JsonSerializer<T> : ISerializer<T>
{
  public void Serialize(T value, IBufferWriter<byte> writer)
  {
     JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Utf8JsonWriter(writer), value);
  }

 public T Deserialize(ref SequenceReader<byte> source)
 {
   var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(source.UnreadSequence);
   var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader)!;
   source.Advance(reader.BytesConsumed);
   return result;
 }
}
```

This doesn't quite work though; e.g.

```
var intSerializer = new JsonSerializer<int>();
intSerializer.Serialize(123, someWriter);
intSerializer.Serialize(456, someWriter);

var value1 = intSerializer.Deserialize(.. some reader based on the previously written data ..)
```

Serialize() would effectively write an UTF8 string of "123456" to the writer, and the subsequent call to Deserialize would read this back in as one number "123456", rather than just the first "123".

What's the most efficient way to circumvent this issue? As a simple solution, I could serialize everything via some `Boxed<T>` reference-container-type. This seems to work out of the box then. But if produces a significant amount of overhead (imagine serializing a million consecutive ints).

Is there a nicer way? Maybe some form of separator character/token that would imply to the Json reader to stop reading, or anything of that sort?

Comment: Serialize as array? `[123,456,{"some":"object"},[true],null]`...

Comment: Unfortunately not possible in this case, the serializer has no particular a priori knowledge if Serialize() will be called once, or multiple times with consecutive elements. (You're right of course that I could serialize an individual element as a one-element array, but I guess that's pretty much the same as using a `Boxed<T>` container type)

Comment: But you do have a serializer instance that can keep state. When nothing is written (or read), write (or consume) the array start.

Comment: I have an x-y feeling, here. Maybe JSON is not the right tool for the usecase?

Comment: @Fildor For rough context - I'm working on a streaming framework that needs to send various types over the wire. Users need to able to configure serializers depending on context and type; e.g. "in pipeline A for type X, use JSON; in pipeline B for type Y, performance requirements are higher, so dear framework, please use my more efficient custom serializer", and so on. And internally, the framework might have its own serializers as well; e.g. "I internally need to transmit a dictionary with my own serializer, which in turn uses the configured user's serializers for key and values separately"

Comment: Well, what does your Utf8JsonWriter write for a single int value? If that's just that value and you write two of them consecutively, how would _any_ human or machine know, that from 123456 they are supposed to read 123 and 456 as two values in opposition to 123456 as one value or 1 and 23456 or 12 and 3456 .... you see where this is going?

Comment: Indeed yes - I was hoping there might eg be some nonprintable character I could manually postfix each element with to signify to the reader to stop reading; similar to how it it (automatically) manages to stop reading after one complex entity (probably by matching closing bracket counts in this case).  If not, looks like i might indeed have to wrap it up in a boxed type